# TreeSet not sorting properly

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, nodes, treeset

I need to keep a sorted list of nodes, starting from the first, which then gets us all the adjacent nodes. The first node, and all other nodes carry a seed value used to determine which node will be used next depending on the lowest seed value, once a node is used to get adjacent nodes it is marked as used, so it doesn't get expanded again even if it has the lowest seed.

My issue is that the used values seem to creep up to the top and halt the search entirely because after 3 iterations the top node will have been a used node that keeps expanding. here's my TreeSet code as well as an example of the numbers creeping up

```
private static TreeSet<Node> nodelist = new TreeSet<Node>(
        new Comparator<Node>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                if (o1.totalVal > o2.totalVal) {
                    if (o2.isValid)
                        return +1;
                    else
                        return -1;
                } else if (o1.totalVal < o2.totalVal)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        });
```

here's the iterations of TreeSet after every set of inserts, everything after the fourth is identical to the fourth, as no new elements can ever read.

```
first set
true, 37.24913792078372
true, 38.12142238654117
true, 38.57602191449718
true, 38.57658845611187
true, 39.427369179869515
false, 36.6742416417845

second set
true, 37.84689665786984
false, 37.24913792078372
true, 38.12142238654117
true, 38.57602191449718
true, 38.57658845611187
true, 39.18376618407356
true, 39.427369179869515
false, 36.6742416417845

third set
true, 38.4682957019364
false, 37.84689665786984
false, 37.24913792078372
true, 38.12142238654117
true, 38.57602191449718
true, 38.57658845611187
true, 39.18376618407356
true, 39.427369179869515
true, 39.814763008775685
false, 36.6742416417845

fourth set
false, 38.4682957019364
false, 37.84689665786984
false, 37.24913792078372
true, 38.12142238654117
true, 38.57602191449718
true, 38.57658845611187
true, 38.590228543643214
true, 39.11409973215888
true, 39.18376618407356
true, 39.427369179869515
true, 39.814763008775685
true, 40.469726317012984
false, 36.6742416417845
```

so far I reasoned that it has to do with the tree structure, but can't really understand why it's doing this. I have tried using a similar approach with a priorityqueue, and sorted arraylist implementation and both did the same, albeit they would get about 2 more iterations before grinding to a halt.

any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you make sure that your compare method obeys its contract?

Comment: this is probably my 8-9th variant of a compare method, most of them follow the same set of rules, that if a totalVal is lower and valid, return +1, if its lower and/or invalid return -1, but on all tries it will get stuck in the aforementioned way.

Comment: @user3213422 Those 2 rules **do not** create an ordering on the objects. No wonder none of your variants worked.

Comment: actually, the second rule was higher, not lower, but regardless...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contract for `Comparator` requires that comparison is stable - i.e. if `compare(a,b) < 0` then `compare(b,a) > 0` etc. It looks like you are not doing that. I suspect you should test `o1.isvalid` in your else block somehow but there isn't enough code to be sure.

You may be better off with something more like:

```
private static TreeSet<Node> nodelist = new TreeSet<Node>(
        new Comparator<Node>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                if ( o1.isValid == o2.isValid ) {
                    // Both valid/invalid - it's the totals that control the order.
                    return o1.totalVal - o2.totalVal;
                } else {
                    // One valid, one not, move all invalids to one end.
                    return o1.isValid ? -1 : 1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry but that doesn't appear to work either, only gets 2 iterations before going on halt, this is the final result
    false, 38.12142238654117
    true, 39.427369179869515
    true, 40.88498168571578
    false, 36.6742416417845

the first false in all my methods will always go straight to the bottom, but that's the only one

Comment: @user3213422 - Not sure what you mean by iterations but this comparator should not sort its elements as `false, true, true, false` as you suggest (assuming the `false/true` in your comment is the `isValid` field of a `Node)`. Please post an mcve as `assylias` suggested so we can test it properly.

Comment: that right there is the bulk of the issue, I have a grid, each point is seeded based on perlin noise, you take the start point, get the eight adjacent points (west, northwest, north, ect) add them to the treeset, mark the current poind invalid, then get the next point out (which should be the one with lowest seeded value that isn't invalid) I really don't know what more code is relevant to the issue of it not sorting properly. although I will point out the current node is marked invalid before any nodes are added in.

Comment: @user3213422 - You may therefore have either or both of two other issues - a) Sorting does not work with 2d data - there must be a stable order for every pair in the collection b) if you change the object after it has been put into the collection it will not be resorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid trying to write your own compare method, because they can be hard to reason about. With [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
private static final TreeSet<Node> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(nodeOrdering);
```

Where `nodeOrdering` is defined as:

```
Comparator<Node> nodeOrdering = Ordering.natural()
    .onResultOf(isValidFunction)
    .compound(Ordering.natural().onResultOf(totalValueFunction));
```

`isValidFunction` is defined like this:

```
Function<Node, Boolean> isValidFunction = new Function<>() {
  @Override public Boolean apply(Node input) { return input.isValid; }
};
```

`totalValueFunction` is defined similarly:

```
Function<Node, Double> totalValueFunction = new Function<>() {
  @Override public Double apply(Node input) { return input.totalVal; }
};
```

Comment: Guava isn't one of our installed libraries, so using it isn't really an option

Comment: it should be, make it so! :)